# Prevent .scroll event from firing every time I scroll in same direction unless done otherwise

Tags: jquery

I've a jquery code that changes my css class when I scroll up/down the page. This solves my purpose but it's firing the event every time I scroll the page and I'm concerned that this may affect the website performance.

So is there any way to make it fire only once unless I scroll in opposite direction?

PS: I don't want to use the mousewheel function for some reasons. Just want to improve this code. I'm not much of coder either so a simple language will be appreciated. :)

Here is my jquery code:

```
$(function(){
var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
var _direction;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(_top < _cur_top)
    {
        _direction = 'down';
        $("#my_div").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    }
    else
    {
        _direction = 'up';
        $("#my_div").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
    }
    _top = _cur_top;
    console.log(_direction);
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/ramansharma89/9sdkyhss/

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/, https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/, https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if you already operated the class change

```
if(_top < _cur_top && _direction !== "down")
{
    // [...]
}
else if(_top >= _cur_top && _direction !== "up")
{
    // [...]
}
```

This will make the callback lightweight and performance won't be affected even with the scroll event fired repeatedly.

Your whole code snippet become:

```
$(function(){
var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
var _direction = "";
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(_top < _cur_top && _direction !== "down")
    {
        _direction = 'down';
        $("#my_div").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
    }
    else if(_top >= _cur_top && _direction !== "up")
    {
        _direction = 'up';
        $("#my_div").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
    }
    _top = _cur_top;
    console.log(_direction);
});
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that you can show this in my example? I'm not much of a coder. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. I really appreciate for sparing time for this. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default the .scroll event fires every time you scroll. But if you want to stop the .addClass .removeClass being repeated, can't you just test the _direction variable?

EG:

```
$(function(){
var _top = $(window).scrollTop();
var _direction;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var _cur_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(_top < _cur_top)
    {
       if(_direction != "down"){
           _direction = 'down';
           $("#my_div").removeClass("up").addClass("down");
        }
    }
    else
    {
       if(_direction != "up"){
           _direction = 'up';
           $("#my_div").removeClass("down").addClass("up");
        }
    }
    _top = _cur_top;
    console.log(_direction);
});
});
```

By the by, if you do want to stop the scroll event firing something every time you scroll, you could use a waitForFinalEvent function, like this:

```
var waitForFinalEvent = (function () {
    var timers = {};
    return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
    if (!uniqueId) {
        uniqueId = "Don't call this twice without a uniqueId";
    }
    if (timers[uniqueId]) {
        clearTimeout (timers[uniqueId]);
    }
    timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();
```

And use it like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    waitForFinalEvent(function(){ // fire event when scroll has finished only
        resizeChecksDelayed();
    }, 500, "all page scripts");
    // Do some stuff in here once I've stopped.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use delays and some checks before dom manipulations:

```
'https://jsfiddle.net/9sdkyhss/1/'
```